# Draw an Image in .NET MAUI using IImage from a Stream

Tags: c#, maui

I retrieved a base64 Image from an api and store it into the model as imageData

```cs
public class Dish
{
    public int? productId { get; set; }
    public string? name { get; set; }
    public decimal? price { get; set; }
    public string? description { get; set; }
    public int? productCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string? notes { get; set; }
    public string? imageData { get; set; }
    public PlatformImage? image { get; set; }
}
```

Right after getting the base64 and parse it into a Bytes stream, I wanted to draw it, please note that this is a List collection and I already tried to load the image from a Memory Stream but I get an error "Closed stream" or something like that, so I was trying a different approach, this is what I'm trying to do, it is self explainable

```cs
foreach (var dish in dishList)
{
    IImage image;
    ICanvas canvas;
    var imagen = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://mydinner.ch/ManagementAPI/api/ProductImages/GetDefaultImageByProductId?productId={dish.productId}");
    var imagenesString = await imagen.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var imagenes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dish>(imagenesString);
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imagenes.imageData.Substring(23));
    var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
   
    image = PlatformImage.FromStream(ms);

  
    if (image != null)
    {
        canvas.DrawImage(image, 10, 10, image.Width, image.Height);
        
    }
}
```

MAUI documentation mention that it is possible to draw it from a stream with a similar code, im actually new with .NET, MAUI and even C# so take in consideration your talking with a newbie, thanks in advance

What I want is to storage the image so I can later display it along with the other model information in its view.

Comment: Do you really need a canvas?  Can you use a standard Image control instead?

Comment: I don't really need a Canvas, all I need is to display the image from the stream, the easiest way is to use the ImageSource.FromStream(), it works but after a few seconds running the app in the android emulator I got this error

 -->"System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'" 

It is inside a foreach to assign every response to a memoryStream and then to the object property with ImageSource.FromStream

Comment: Why are you downloading the stream yourself?